# After Effects Extendscript - changing the centerpoint for addlight

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

Using this example code:

```
app.project.item(index).layers.addLight(name, centerPoint)
```

I created the following test code where I add a light to my second scene (composition) in my project to create a shadow:

```
var s2light1 = scene2.layers.addLight("s2light1", [1143,121]);
```

This works perfectly. But I now also want to set the 3rd (Z) value for the centerPoint in Extendscript (as is possible in After Effects).

However according to the After Effects CS6 scripting guide it seems you can only set the X and Y values: "*The center of the new camera, a floating-point array [x, y]. This is used to set the initial x and y values of the new camera’s Point of Interest property. The z value is set to 0.*"

Is there another approach or work around to set the Z-value for the center point in Extendscript which I can try?

Comment: Just curious what happens when you add the third value to the array in the second param?  Like [1143,121,400] do you get an error?  You might also try using the position layer.property("Position").setValue([x,y,z]) method after you create the light.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ariestav. If I add another parameter I get an error because only 2 parameters are allowed ("value array does not have 2 elements").

Comment: The position property is indeed enough to manipulate the light in desired position for what I want to do in this project. 
Seems that the Z value for the centerPoint is not available in ExtendScript.

Comment: Cool!  Glad it works.  Maybe an up vote for my comment?

Comment: Would love to do that, but I'm a new user so don't think I can yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newLight = app.project.item(1).layers.addLight("foo", [22, 33]);
//now set the point of interest ('center point') value:
newLight.property("Point of Interest").setValue([22, 33, 11]);
```

and to make a light not auto-orient (one-node):

```
newLight.autoOrient = AutoOrientType.NO_AUTO_ORIENT;
```

In which case you would control the Position and Rotation properties -- no point of interest.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing this 'property' approach.